# from PySide2.QtCore import * ImportError: libpcre.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyside2

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. I do `pip3 install PySide2` and when I run the script, it shows the error, I have already try the methods something like `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev`, it just shows `libglib2.0-dev is already the newest version (2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.6).`

I have set the path in my .bashrc, like this : `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. After set this, I got another error like `ImportError: libpcre.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. I can not solve it. Please help me out. Also, I need to use pycharm to write the code, so if anyone knows how to configure in pycharm, please leave the comments. Thanks.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libpcre3` then.

Comment: Yeah I try that, it shows me `libpcre3 is already the newest version (2:8.39-12ubuntu0.1).`

Comment: @XiaoLx Why not install the offical ubuntu pyside2 packages?

Comment: oh, I thought `pip3` is the official way to install it.